# Change example.com/dashboard.php to example.com/index.php?action=dashboard

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

I would like to change my site page URLs from
the following:

```
mysite.com/profile.php
```

to

```
mysite.com/index.php?action=profile
```

What language would work for this? I tried a bunch of `.htacesss` codes but none seem to work!  Any `.htacess` suggestions?

My code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule   ^profile.php(.+)$   /index.php?action=$1   [L]
```

Comment: What did you try that didn't work?

Comment: i just edited it sorry

Answer (score 0):

Why not just put redirect code on index.php so that if a $_GET['action'] variable exists and points to 'profile' you'll be redirected to profile.php?

Otherwise I believe .htaccess is what you're going to have to use to address this redirection/URL rewrite.

Put this at the top of you index.php page...

```
<?php

    if ($_GET['action'] == "profile") {
        echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; url=profile.php' />";
    }

?>
```

Also, check this out. http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/02/introduction-to-url-rewriting/

Answer (score 0):

Using htaccess redirects is ususaaly used the other way, when we want to have clean URL'S , didnt see much that work the other way but it is of course possible. I agree with @ScottCarmichael that if you are working with querystrings PHP if statement (or switch) is a good solution (but i prefere usin  `hearder()` function rather than refresh ) , then you can have an include on the top with a PHP script with all conditions.

If you still think htaccess is the way for you, try this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^profile.php$ index.php?action=profile [R,L]
```